# read csv from pandas issues (delimiters or separators not working)

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv

My raw data in csv format is as below

```
text,location,user_follower_count,user_verified
shameful  a poor man from bihar is killed  j amp k administration under central rule did not even arrange for his body to be flown,NA,NA,NA
being right about anything can be its own reward  but you migh    more for aquarius,NA,NA,NA
they don t want herd immunity  they want a herd mentality,NA,NA,NA
```

I am trying to read the above file as follows.

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv(raw_tweet_data,sep=",", header='infer')
```

But everything gets deleted jammed under column (text).  location,user_follower_count,user_verified columns are "Nan".
I tried both "delimiters" and "sep". Both don't work. Why is it so?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was because of "NA" string in columns like location, user_follower_count and user_verified
Pandas is reading "NA" string as Nan. Once I changed the string "NA" to "not available", issue got resolved. Bit tricky. Thanks.

Comment: Could've also been solved by specifying the na_values parameter as an empty dict
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

try to mention the columns when reading along with other parameters like pd.read_csv(columns=[...]) once I faced this type of problem by mentioning the column names it was solved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried as raw_data = pd.read_csv(raw_tweet_data, names=["text", "location", "user_follower_count", "user_verified"], delimiter=",") but still didn'y solve the original problem.